# How to reload carouse items onPainted? Sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, carousel

I would like to reload items in the carousel `onPainted()` method. So whenever users come the carousel item then we have a fresh list of carousel items. Problem at this point of time (please have a look at the source code), the carousel reloads items, however until I touch the carousel, the first carousel item is blank (or not selected) and no items selected. I would like at least to see the first element to be selected.

So here is the simplified source code:

```
Ext.define("APN.view.FeaturedCarousel", {
    config: {
        listeners: {
            painted: function(carousel, eOpts) {
                var features_url = Ext.getStore("regionalisation").getRegionalisedMenus().feature.url;
                this.setCarouselStore(features_url);
            }
        }
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.callParent();
        var me = this;
        var features_url = Ext.getStore("regionalisation").getRegionalisedMenus().feature.url;
        this.setCarouselStore(features_url);
    },
    setCarouselStore: function (features_url) {
        var me = this;

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: features_url,
            success: function (response) {
                me.removeAll();
                if (!xml) return;

                var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    fields: [
                    ],
                    data: xml,
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'memory',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'xml',
                            rootProperty: 'xml',
                            record: 'item'
                        }
                    }
                });

                store.each(function (record) {
                    var item = Ext.create("Ext.Container", {
                        html: "some HTML HERE"
                    });

                    me.add(item);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should activate the first item in the carousel once all the items are added. Like this:

```
  store.each(function (record) {
    var item = Ext.create("Ext.Container", {
      html: "some HTML HERE"
    });

    me.add(item);
  });

  me.setActiveItem(0);
```

This should make the first item selected.

If you want to change the carousel content every time it is activated, use "`active`" listener. Because "`painted`" will be called only once and if you want that, then no point in adding a `painted` event because you are already calling the "`setCarouselStore`" function in "`initialize`" method.

Comment: So I thought you might know the answer on this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726448/how-to-remove-all-items-from-ext-ux-slidenavigation-view

Comment: Ok, I gave an answer there. Also, you can check a simpler slide navigation here : http://innofied.com/slide-navigation-with-sencha-touch/