# How to remove all items from Ext.ux.slidenavigation.View

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

So here is the plugin that I'm using for slidenavigation: [slidenavigation](https://github.com/wnielson/sencha-SlideNavigation), and I would like to remove all items on painted method.

It seems that items are stored in `this.data.items`. However clearing an array doesn't solve an issue.

CLearing the store didn't as well. So here is the painted method to initialise the items and push them to the plugin

```
Ext.define("APN.view.FlyoutNavigation", {
    id: "flyoutNavigationPanel",
    extend: 'Ext.ux.slidenavigation.View',
    },
    listeners:
    {
        painted: function() {
            this.store.clear()
            this.store.data.clear()
            this.store.items = []

            var arrItems = [
            .. heaps of items in here
            ]

            this.addItems(arrItems);

        },
    },
```

And in the plugin `addItems` method:

```
    addItems: function(items) {
        console.log("data from addItems:")
        console.log(this.store)
        var me = this,
            items = Ext.isArray(items) ? items : [items],
            groups = me.config.groups;

        Ext.each(items, function(item, index) {
            if (!Ext.isDefined(item.index)) {
                item.index = me._indexCount;
                me._indexCount++;
            }
            me.store.add(item);
            console.log("data from addItems after adding:")
            console.log(me.store.data.all.length)
        });
        console.log("data from addItems after adding:")
        console.log(this.store)
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
this.store.remove(this.store.getRange());
```

This should clear out the store.

Comment: Do you want to check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142028/how-to-add-tap-event-to-youtube-iframe

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all the items from DOM, you have to get all the items and call [destroy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-destroy) method on them

Comment: Cool, you directed me to the right direction, however this was not the solution.

I had to explicitly declare `removeItems()` method.